# Why disabling node in ExtJs makes checkbox still available?

Tags: javascript, magento, extjs, nodes, treenode

I'm working with ExtJs bundled with Magento to disable category nodes from a row after checking a node.

I'm able to disable nodes from same 'level' but checkbox inputs still available to check them.

This is my code so far:

```
tree.on('check', function(node) {
    if(node.attributes.checked) {
        categoryAdd(node.id);
        //disable nodes except checked Node
        for (var i = 0; i < node.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var actualNode = node.parentNode.childNodes[i];
            if (!actualNode.attributes.checked) {
                actualNode.disable();
            }
        }
    } else {
        categoryRemove(node.id);
        //enable all nodes
        for (var i = 0; i < node.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var actualNode = node.parentNode.childNodes[i];
            actualNode.enable();
        }
    }
    varienElementMethods.setHasChanges(node.getUI().checkbox);
}, tree);
```

And this is a capture to understand what this code does.
[image]

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle? When I click into your image, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable or set input to read-only mode you should use [DomQuery](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.DomQuery.html#events) and set attributes to each input:

```
var readonly = true;
var checkBoxes = Ext.DomQuery.select("DIV[@id='" + myTreeid + "']")[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
Ext.each(checkBoxes, function(cb){
   cb.setAttribute('disabled', readonly);
});
```